# WPF Modern UI Chart Xaml Chart Title style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Tenho o gráfico abaixo e gostaria de alterar o tamanho da fonte para a propriedade ChartTitle, se possível pelo xaml.

Na classe do chart consigo alterar o tamanho da fonte das séries através da propriedade chart.FontSize, mas não encontrei um método para alterar o ChartTitle.

```
<chart:ClusteredColumnChart
    x:Name="chtComparativaAtual"
    Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
    ChartTitle="Evolução Comparativa (Atual)"  
    Background="White"
    Foreground="#444444"
    Grid.Row="1"    
    Grid.Column="1"
    Width="auto"
    Height="400"
    Palette="{StaticResource Cores}" 
    ChartSubTitle="" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    >
    <chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="chart:ColumnPiece">
            <Setter 
            Property="Margin" 
            Value="4,0"
            />
        </Style>
    </chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Resources>

    <chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series>
        <chart:ChartSeries
            x:Name="dcComparativaAtual"              
            DisplayMember="Categoria"
            ValueMember="Valor"
            Foreground="White"
            SeriesTitle="Pendências"
            Width="auto"
            />
    </chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series>

</chart:ClusteredColumnChart>
```

Propriedades referente ao ChartTitle:

```
chtComparativaAtual.ChartTitle
chtComparativaAtual.ChartTitleStyle
```

ChartTitle: string
ChartTitleStyle: System.Windows.Style ChartBase.ChartTitleStyle